# One to Many Relationships concerning Attribute Tables and Domains in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, domains, one-to-many, attribute-assistant

I am drawing in and inventorying signalized intersection assets and when it comes to the conduit and wiring some of the conduits (most) have 2+ cable/wire conduits in them.

For example, the record drawing below shows an HDPE schedule 80 conduit that contains inside 4 cable/wire conduits (9C/14 , 7C/14 , 6-5C/14 , 2-2C/16).
I have created domains for the type of conduit (NEC_Conduit) and quantity of cable/wire conduits (count_Conduit).

My goal is to field calculate the type_Conduit field using the simple expression of type_Conduit = "count_Conduit"& &"NEC_Conduit". The issue is is there is a one to many relationship. The NEC_ and count_ Conduit fields contain more than one record per one line feature and the type_Conduit would have multiple records per feature for some (many) features.

How would I set my domains and tables up to accomplish this (if possible)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I am not using the tool to grid out areas, I am just making polygons that are based on intersections ID points as my grid feature for the Generate_ID_By_Intersect. So instead of the data residing directly in the features attribute data, I am going to create an ID for each line of conduit and in the related table I will show show the attribute assistant generated ID.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have yet to get the formula to run correctly.

Comment: Are you proposing concatenating the two fields into type_Conduit?   I am not sure what the advantage is of a domain on a field that is not entered by the user, but calculated.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to concatenate the two fields. I have ditched this method and am going to use the attribute assistant to help create related tables; which I am having trouble setting up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got to work through trial and error. Only issue is the  desired output for the ConduitID will be alphanumeric...unless you can find a way around it.

[image]